# Can I change which topic usb_cam is publishing?

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I change the topic which each node publishes? I'm using usb_cam with multiple nodes and each node will run in different devices, I need them to publish on different topics so the server can send them instructions individually.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355227/can-i-change--which-topic-usb_cam-is-publishing?/) by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-06-18**:
Have you tried to remap the topics ?

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-18**:
oh, hello! thanks for commenting.
Yes, I've tried to change the `<remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>`   to `<remap from="image" to="/raspImages"/>`   but it just throw a error on image_view, saying that it couldn't read from that topic, so the remap worked for changing what topic a node should subscribe but I don't know how to make it change a publisher's topic.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-06-18**:
Can you show the full launch file please ? There might be more remapping required.

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-18**:
`<launch> <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" > <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" /> <param name="image_width" value="640" /> <param name="image_height" value="480" /> <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" /> <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" /> <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/> </node> <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen"> <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/> <param name="autosize" value="true" /> </node> </launch>`

from [link text](https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam/blob/develop/launch/usb_cam-test.launch)

I just switched the image_view remap. Which... thinking about it now, the image_view is just the visualization node, I think, it's supposed to not be able to subscribe to a different node that the node called usb_cam is publishing...but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remap will do what you're wanting: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

ex.

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load image_proc/crop_decimate realsense2_camera_manager"
      name="$(arg camera)_depth_image_decimator" respawn="true"  output="screen">
  <remap from="points"     to="/$(arg camera)/depth/points" /> 
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-18**:
I'm gonna try here! thanks for help!

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-06-18**:
Ok, I tested here. It worked!! thanks a lot, I'm newbie in ROS haha.